# Indian partner of EU citizen applying to join wife in Germany

Tags: eu-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and I am married to a French citizen living in Germany. I was on a tourist visa when we got married in Denmark. I am going back to India before the expiration of my visa.

In order to join my wife in Germany, what kind of visa should I apply for and what documents are required?

Do I benefit from being the partner of an EU citizen and does that mean my visa processing will be expedited (or take months)?

Comment: Do you want to move to Germany? If so, your question is off topic here. Have a look at [Expatriates.SE], and if existing questions there don't help you adequately, ask a new one there. Search terms you'll find useful: `freedom of movement`; `2004/38/EC`. Also note that you don't actually need to leave Germany if you don't want to, because as the spouse of an EU citizen, you are already a "person enjoying freedom of movement under union law" when you're with your spouse (unless the Germans challenge your marriage as a marriage of convenience and the challenge succeeds).

Comment: You can apply for long term visa or residence permit to live in Germany under family unification. http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/Familiennachzug/familiennachzug-node.html

Comment: @pbu the link u mentioned is related to family members of third country nationals but I am a family member of eu citizen.

Comment: @phoog I am sorry. I want to move to Germany  and I guess my question is off topic here.

Comment: @RahulMehra But you are not EU citizen by yourself, that means you are third country national

Comment: @pbu Yes but not a member of the family of a third country national, that's a big difference and *Familiennachzug* is not exactly the right procedure. For example, the whole business about speaking German and exceptions to this requirement does not apply.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks for clearing it, I got confused. The link is for ppl who are family member of third country nationals and not for family members of eu citizens.

Comment: @pbu the OP is the primary applicant, it's not a chain migration scenario

Comment: No need to apologize; just post the question at [Expatriates.SE] and delete this one, or flag this one for migration.  It's a good question for Expatriates.